# how to switch the texture of render target in three js?

Tags: three.js, textures

I need to perform some calculation based on texture.

I have two textures: current texture and next texture. The content of the next texture depends on the current texture.

Here is the procedure of my program

1. Initialize the current texture and next texture

   ```
   let array = new Float32Array(3 * amount);
   array = init(array);
   currentTexture= new THREE.DataTexture(array ,
       textureSize, textureSize,
       THREE.RGBFormat, THREE.FloatType);

   let textureOptions = {
       format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
       type: THREE.FloatType
   };
   nextTexture= new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(textureSize, textureSize, textureOptions);
   ```
2. render to next texture and swap the current texture and next texture for next render

   ```
   renderer.render(scene, camera, nextTexture);
   let temp = mesh.material.uniforms.currentTexture.value;
   mesh.material.uniforms.currentTexture.value = nextTexture.texture;
   mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
   nextTexture.texture = temp;
   ```

But my program doesn't work, the browser console is full of `GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same`. I think this is because the current texture and next texture are not swapped successfully.

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can modify the `texture` field of a RenderTarget. It sounds like what you want is two RenderTargets that you swap between rendering and a DataTexture that you use to seed the contents of the first render target, is that right?

Comment: Hi, @GarrettJohnson, thanks for your advice. It seems that it's the only way to achieve my goal, because I can't see any method in the document to init RenderTarget with data. Anyway, I will take your advice.

Comment: Great! I made an answer to give a bit more detail and show some example code. Let me know if it needs more clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify a Render Target's `texture` field so you'll need two render textures and to use one as a render target and one as a mesh texture. You'll have to seed the initial render target with the data by some means like rendering a full screen quad to the Render Target first.

Here's an example of what the initialization might look like:

```
let array = new Float32Array(3 * amount);
array = init(array);

let dataTex = new THREE.DataTexture(array,
    textureSize, textureSize,
    THREE.RGBFormat, THREE.FloatType);

// Create the textures to swap
let textureOptions = {
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    type: THREE.FloatType
};
let currentTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(textureSize, textureSize, textureOptions);
let nextTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(textureSize, textureSize, textureOptions);

// material with shader to render next frame based on the current texture
const material = /* custom material */; 

// ... init the current texture by rendering a quad with the data texture to seed the texture
```

And then rendering the textures before swapping them:

```
// render the animation step
material.uniforms.currentTexture.value = currentTexture.texture;
renderer.render(scene, camera, nextTexture);

// swap the textures
let temp = currentTexture;
currentTexture = nextTexture;
nextTexture = temp;
```

Hope that helps!